# exchange power-shell script to email distribution list owners

Tags: powershell, email, exchange-server

I am having a bit of a tough time writing a script for exchange. I have an environment, that has a hybird environment. I am trying to make a power shell script to find all large distro groups and email the owners of the groups to clean them up. However, I am having issues with pulling the owner email and and name for the email portion of the script.

But, there are a few restrictions, I can't use AD powershell, exchange only. and  I can't use the get-mailbox cmdlet.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.e2010
set the scope of the search
Set-ADServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true
$DistGroups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize 2 
  ForEach ($Group in $DistGroups) {
    #Get each group details

    $MemberCount = (Get-DistributionGroupMember $Group).count  
    $GroupName = (Get-DistributionGroup $Group).DisplayName  
    $Owner = (Get-DistributionGroup $Group).ManagedBy
    $OwnerEmail = Get-recipient -identity $Owner | select PrimarySmtpAddress   
    $OwnerFN = Get-Recipient -identity  $Owner | Select FirstName 

    If ( $MemberCount > 50000) {

      #define email stuff

      $messageBody =  "Hi, <b>$OwnerFN,</b><p>" 
      $messageBody += "We are auditing distribution groups in our environment and your group, $GroupName, was flagged as being 
        <font color=red>really large</font>. The current member count is <font color=red> $MemberCount</font>.<p>" 
      $messageBody += "Please take steps to update the group and clear out unnecessary or old group members… <p>"
      $messageBody += "Thanks, <p>" 
      $messageBody += "The Exchange Admin Team"

      #Send the mail

      $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
      $email.From = "Email_Group_Admin_Report@Internal.Mail.company.com"
      $email.To.Add("me@company.com")
      #$email.To.Add("$OwnerEmail")
      #$email.CC.Add("@company.com")
      #$email.BCC.Add("admin@company.com")
      $email.DeliveryNotificationOptions =           [System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions]::OnSuccess
      $email.IsBodyHtml = $True
      $email.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
      $email.Subject = "Distribution Group Audit"
      $email.Body = $messageBody | Out-String
      $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
      $smtp.Host = "mail.compnany.com"
      $smtp.Send($email)       
    }
 }
```

I am able to get the count, and the Distro name, I can't seem to get the managed by property or the other stuff, it spits out an entire list of primary emails and Firstnames and such... The managed by property doesn't seem to appear....

Answer (score 1):

> `$OwnerEmail = Get-recipient -identity $Owner | select PrimarySmtpAddress`

This will return an object, but when you send the email you're acting as if you have a string.

> `email.To.Add("$OwnerEmail")`

Option A:

```
($OwnerEmail = Get-recipient -identity $Owner).PrimarySmtpAddress 
email.To.Add($OwnerEmail)
```

Option B:

```
$OwnerEmail = Get-recipient -identity $Owner | select PrimarySmtpAddress
email.To.Add($OwnerEmail.PrimarySmtpAddress)
```

Comment: also: `$OwnerEmail = Get-recipient -identity $Owner | select -ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress`

Comment: I will give it a whirl... Thanks for the help, Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I had a tough time with the output formats, but I finally got it working as expected. Thought I would post the working script here... Maybe you will find it useful.

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.e2010

# Find all Distros
$DistGroups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize unlimited
  ForEach ($Group in $DistGroups) {
        #Get each group details
        if ($Group.managedby -ne $null) {

        $t = $Group.Managedby
        $t | foreach {  $Owner = $_.Name }  
        }
        else {
        $Owner = "Unknown"
        $DL_Name = $Group.displayname

         }
         $MemberCount = (Get-DistributionGroupMember $Group).count 


        if ($Owner -eq "Unknown") { echo "The owner is unknown!"
          } 
        #set membercount catch here
        elseIf ( $MemberCount -gt 2000) { 


            $OwnerEm = get-recipient $Owner | select PrimarySmtpAddress |           ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string
            #$OwnerEm = get-recipient me@company.com | select PrimarySmtpAddress | ft -HideTableHeaders | out-string

            #define email stuff

            $messageBody =  "Hi, <b>$Owner,</b><p>" 
            $messageBody += "We are auditing distribution groups in our environment and your group, $DL_Name, was flagged as being <font color=red>really large</font>. The current member count is <font color=red> $MemberCount</font>.<p>" 
            $messageBody += "Please take steps to update the group and clear out unnecessary or old group members… <p>"
            $messageBody += "Thanks, <p>" 
            $messageBody += "The Exchange Admin Team"

            #Send the mail

            $email = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $email.From = "Email_Group_Admin_Report@Internal.Mail.company.com"
            #$email.To.Add("me@company.com")
            $email.To.Add("$OwnerEm")
            #$email.CC.Add("@company.com")
            #$email.BCC.Add("admin@company.com")
            $email.DeliveryNotificationOptions = [System.Net.Mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions]::OnSuccess
            $email.IsBodyHtml = $True
            $email.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
            #$attachment = "C:\myfile.txt"
            #$email.Attachments.Add( $attachment )
            $email.Subject = "Distribution Group Audit"
            $email.Body = $messageBody | Out-String
            $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
            $smtp.Host = "mail.company.com"
            $smtp.Send($email)
             echo "the $DL_Name has a high member count. The member count is $MemberCount.  The manager has been sent and email at $OwnerEm"
            } 
            else {
            echo "the $DL_Name seems fine! The member count is $MemberCount.  The manager '$Owner' is doing great!"
                }
      }
```

I left the echo statements in so you can view  the statuses via a console, or pipe them to a file.... or something...